# Unity3d: clamp magnitude to only x axis

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

Using Unity3d 4.1.2, C# mono.

go the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float MoveSpeed = 30.0f;

public float maxVel = 0.000000001f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //Physics.gravity = Vector3(0,-50,0);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    maxVel = 20f;
    MoveSpeed = 50.0f;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * MoveSpeed);
        Debug.Log("BEFORE = " + rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.left * MoveSpeed);
    }

    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rigidbody.velocity, maxVel);
    Debug.Log("AFTER = " + rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}
}
```

As you can see works fine, had some problems with the clamp but finally got it to work.

there is one problem...

In unity's physic's engine, i changed the y value to be -30, and set the material "bounce" to 1, so it loses no energy.

problem is my clamp is clamping the rebound effect because the clamp effects all Axis :(
Thus the rigidbody never returns to its y position.

is there a way to change the clamp to only effect the x Axis?  i haven't been able to find any information on this.

cheers guys

Comment: Not at a computer with unity on right now so I'm guessing, but have you looked at the editor interface for the rigidbody component? There's a couple of axis specific locks there. I know one is rotation but not sure on the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, clamp only x value:

```
Vector3 clampVel = rigidBody.velocity;
clampVel.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampVel.x, min, max);

rigidBody.velocity = clampVel;
```